# How to remove all siblings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, siblings

I have four images and I want to remove the other 3 when anyone is clicked.

I could do it one by one with:

```
function removeimages() {
var elem = document.getElementById('image1');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

but that is not practical.

What is the best way to remove all the siblings (images) except the one clicked?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Show us the code that you have been trying before you posted your question.

Comment: allthethings.onclick = function(){ for(var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++){ if(document.images[i] == this)continue;document.images[i].parentNode.removeChild(document.images[i]);} };

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you try to use jquery to manipulate the DOM? It will be much easier and be supported by most browsers. The code is as follows:

```
$("#imgContainer img").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().remove();
});
```

Please have a look at this working version:
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bruceyang/dzPt4/)